# PowerShell Get-CrmConnection in XrmTooling is not working anymore

Tags: powershell, power-platform, p-lang, xrm-tooling-connector

I have a piece of PowerShell code that generates `CrmConnection`. I tried this code 4-5 months ago and it did work. However, for some reason i am getting the below error while running it now. I can confirm `$clientId`, `$clientSecret`, `$url` are correct.

The code,

```
function New-PP-Connection
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $clientId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $clientSecret,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $url
    )
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    $moduleName = "Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnector.PowerShell"
    $connectionString = "AuthType=ClientSecret;url=$url;ClientId=$clientId;ClientSecret=$clientSecret"

    if(-not(Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name $moduleName)){
        Install-Module $moduleName -Scope CurrentUser
    }
    Import-Module $moduleName

    write-host "Creating dynamics connection"
    $crmClient = Get-CrmConnection -ConnectionString $connectionString;
    write-host "Crm Client Created"  
}
```

Screenshot of the error
[image]

error text,

> Get-CrmConnection : Failed to connect to CRM: Invalid Login Information : The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'

I have seen a similar issue in GitHub https://github.com/microsoft/coe-starter-kit/issues/2564 however no exact solution has been provided.

Comment: Your code was working.  So either the token expired, the login data on server changed, or the authentication method was changed on the server.  Many systems have switched from Windows Credentials to OAUTH2.  OAUTH2 is supported on Windows, MAC, and Linux.

Comment: it is using oauth. it uses clientsecret - as in authcode flow for non-iteractive users

Comment: The token may of expired.  Make sure you are getting a new token.  When getting token make sure you are getting 200 OK,

Comment: i'd have thought `Get-CrmConnection` encapsulates that. if not and i have to generate a token to reauth, how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have come across a bug in `Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnector.PowerShell` where the above code only works if there is one secret per app registration. I had two secrets for this app registration. As soon as I removed one it started working.